# I can't see scroll bar on ScrollViewer

Tags: uwp-xaml

I am displaying scrollable list on SplitView.
Scrolling works fine, but there is one problem.
[image]

As you can see, I can't see scroll bar.
If I make ScrollViewer smaller, the scroll bar appears. But when maximized, I can't see it.

Here is my XAML code.

```
<Page
    x:Class="Memoify.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Memoify"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="MainColor">#FFFFCC00</Color>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid"  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="48" Margin="0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" StrokeThickness="0" Grid.Column="1">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource MainColor}"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

        <TextBlock x:Name="UICurrentCategory" Text="ALL MEMOS"  Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="53,8,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <SplitView x:Name="UISplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" CompactPaneLength="0"  OpenPaneLength="320" Margin="0,0,-31,0" Grid.Column="1">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <!-- NOTE: Below ScrollViewer shows scroll bar well -->
                <ScrollViewer  Margin="0,48,0,0">
                    <ListView x:Name="UIMenuList" Margin="0,0,0,0" IsItemClickEnabled="True"  ItemClick="UIMenuList_ItemClick"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <SplitView.Content>
                <ScrollViewer  Margin="0,48,0,0">
                    <ListView x:Name="UIMemoList" Margin="0,0,0,0" IsItemClickEnabled="True"  ItemClick="UIMenuList_ItemClick" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>
        <Button x:Name="UIMenuButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="OpenCloseMenu" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="20" Width="48" Height="48" Padding="0" UseSystemFocusVisuals="True" Content="&#xE700;" Grid.Column="1">
            <Button.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource MainColor}"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I believe something is wrong with width of ScrollView(or ListView inside of it?), but how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove your margin Margin="0,0,-31,0" on the splitview

It should fix your issue.
Can you please mark as solved if it does ?
Thanks